# Unable to resolve path [Player.playerName_en], unexpected token [Player]

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have this error can any one help me please

**Here is my stacktrace:**

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: Unable to resolve path [Player.playerName_en], unexpected token [Player] [SELECT NEW PlayerTransient .
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    try {
            String sql="SELECT NEW PlayerTransient (Player.playerName_en,Player.playerName_fr,Player.playerName_ar,Player.playerName_Abreviation, Player.playerImage,preference_player.identifier) FROM Player left join preference_player on Player.playerId= preference_player.playerId and preference_player.identifier=Player.identifier";
        playerTransients =  session.createQuery(sql).list();
        tx.commit();


    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }

    return playerTransients;
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your HQL query:

1/You've missed the alias after Player classname :

```
from Player as Player
```

2/ Your join clause `left join preference_player on Player.playerId= preference_player.playerId` is not correct you have to put :

```
left join Player.preference_player // without the on part (which is sql syntax)
```

Here the complete query :

```
SELECT NEW PlayerTransient (Player.playerName_en,Player.playerName_fr,Player.playerName_ar,Player.playerName_Abreviation, Player.playerImage,preference_player.identifier) FROM Player as Player
left join Player.preference_player  where Player.preference_player.identifier=Player.identifier;
```

Comment: preference_player is a jointable between member and player so player dont have a identifier thanks for your answer